# Pulling text from a scraped page with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

New to programming and web scraping and having some trouble getting BeautifulSoup to pull only the text from a given page.

Here's what I'm working with right now:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.tsn.ca/panarin-tops-2019-free-agent-frenzy-class-1.1303592'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

players = soup.find_all('td').text
print(players)
```

Which returns the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tsn.py", line 10, in <module>
    players = soup.find_all('td').text
  File "/home/debian1/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1620, in __getattr__
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

I have also seen `.get_text()` used in BS documentation but that returns the same error.

Comment: Does `find_all` return a list, thats what the error says. what if you do `soup.find_all('td')[0].text`, what version of BeautifulSoup are you using. Also I would recommend `lxml` over BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution was correct. You get a list of values from the `find_all()` method. all you have to do is iterate it and get the required text. I have corrected the code and put it below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.tsn.ca/panarin-tops-2019-free-agent-frenzy-class-1.1303592'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

# This is how you should have extracted the text from the ResultSet

players = [elem.text for elem in soup.find_all('td')]
print(players)
```

Answer (score 1):

`find_all()` will return a list of all elements meeting your specifications. Even if only a single item, or no item is found it will return `[item]` or `[]` respectively. To get the text you will need to index to the item like:

```
players_list = soup.find_all('td')
for player in players_list:
    print(player.text)
```

I use `.getText()` in my scripts, I'm not sure if `.text` works the same or not!

Answer (score 1):

That error indicates that you should iterate over each item like this:

```
players = [item.text for item in soup.find_all('td')] # Iterate over every item and extract the text

print(players)  
print("".join(players)) # If you want all the text in one string
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is a working script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.tsn.ca/panarin-tops-2019-free-agent-frenzy-class-1.1303592'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

players = []
tbl = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'stats-table-scrollable article-table'})
tbl_body = tbl.find('tbody')
rows = tbl_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    columns = row.find_all('td')
    columns = [c.text for c in columns]
    players.append(columns[1])
print(players)
```

Result:

```
['Artemi Panarin', 'Erik Karlsson', 'Sergei Bobrovsky', 'Matt Duchene', 'Jeff Skinner', 'Anders Lee', 'Joe Pavelski', 'Brock Nelson', 'Tyler Myers', 'Mats Zuccarello', 'Alex Edler', 'Gustav Nyquist', 'Jordan Eberle', 'Micheal Ferland', 'Jake Gardiner', 'Ryan Dzingel', 'Kevin Hayes', 'Brett Connolly', 'Marcus Johansson', 'Braydon Coburn', 'Wayne Simmonds', 'Brandon Tanev', 'Joonas Donskoi', 'Colin Wilson', 'Ron Hainsey']
```